# Modifying and saving a value in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code that finds all projects with members that include the inputted email address. The idea is it searches for NFtest@test.com (as an example) and changes it to their inputted name.

**Code in question**

```
Project.find({ _members: req.body.email }, function(err, projects) {
  for (var i = 0, len = projects.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var x = 0, lent = projects[i]._members.length; x < lent; x++) {
      if (projects[i]._members[x] == ["NF" + req.body.email]) {
        console.log("FOUND MATCH")
        projects[i]._members[x].value = req.body.alias
        projects[i].save()
      }
    }
  }
```

Console log tells me that the match has been found, however the value is never updated in the array. I was wondering if there is a correct method to change the value in an array rather than just using the = operator. Or am I not saving the document correctly?

**Sample Project Document**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5546"),
"name" : "Test project",
"description" : "This is a sample description",
"archived" : false,
"admins" : [
       "test@test.com"
],
"_members" : [
        "membertoupdate@test.com",
        "NFmembertoupdate@test.com"
],
"updated" : ISODate("2015=05=04T04:52:22:787Z")
```

The idea is to update NFmembertoupdate@test.com with a name. This name comes from req.body.alias.

The console tells me a match is found and no errors are thrown, however the update is not made.

Comment: Can you at least show us some sample documents and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

**Q.** Why don't my changes to arrays get saved when I update an element directly?

```
doc.array[3] = 'changed';
doc.save();
```

**A.** Mongoose doesn't create getters/setters for array indexes; without them mongoose never gets notified of the change and so doesn't know to persist the new value. The work-around is to use MongooseArray#set available in Mongoose >= 3.2.0.

```
// 3.2.0
doc.array.set(3, 'changed');
doc.save();

// if running a version less than 3.2.0, you must mark the array modified before saving.
doc.array[3] = 'changed';
doc.markModified('array');
doc.save();
```

From the [Mongoose FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html)